# How to clone a BlockingQueue in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, queue, clone

In my Java Application I have

```
BlockingQueue<HashMap<Integer, double[]>> q
```

How do I clone it?

Comment: `BlockingQueue` does not implement `Clonable` interface. Iterate over elements and copy it to a new queue

Comment: How? My need is to have a copy of q without modifying q in any way. Iterating over the elements and doing a q.take() would alterate original queue q.

Comment: LinkedBlockingQueue and ArrayBlockingQueue both have overloaded constructors that take another Collection as parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. *Basic copy* : copy of the `Queue`

   ```
   BlockingQueue<HashMap<Integer, double[]>> q; // = ...
   BlockingQueue<HashMap<Integer, double[]>> copy = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(q);
   ```

---

2. *Deep copy* : copy of the `Queue` and the `Map`'s

   ```
   BlockingQueue<HashMap<Integer, double[]>> q; // = ...
   BlockingQueue<HashMap<Integer, double[]>> copy = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();//or other

   for(HashMap<Integer, double[]> map : q){
       copy.add(new HashMap<>(map));
   }
   ```

---

3. *Very deep copy* :  copy of the `Queue`, the `Map`'s and the `double[]`'s

   ```
   BlockingQueue<HashMap<Integer, double[]>> q; // = ...
   BlockingQueue<HashMap<Integer, double[]>> copy = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();//or other

   for(HashMap<Integer, double[]> map : q){
       Map<Integer, double[]> mapCopy = new HashMap<>();
       for(Map.Entry<Integer, double[]> entry : map.entrySet()){
           double[] array = entry.getValue();
           mapCopy.put(entry.getKey(), Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length));
       }
       copy.add(mapCopy);
   }
   ```

Comment: @Employee your suggested edit does not improve and make the post less readable. Also, it seems logical (or it has to be) that a `BlockingQueue<HashMap<>>` will accept only `HashMap`

Comment: @Employee you can only get the error if you change the code ^^ and If won't add the hundreds of possible errors if modifying the post